# sum of child items in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Given the following...

```
 $itemarray = array()

  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "4.00"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "1766"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "5.00"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "1778"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "5.00"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "1780"
    }
  }
```

I would like to get the sum of `array[x][0]`. At the moment I can get the total sum of each array using

```
  $item_sum = array_sum($itemarray[$x]);
```

I thought `$item_sum = array_sum($itemarray[$x][0]);` might be the way but it would appear not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($itemarray as $x) {
  $sum += $x[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get the first elements sum, you could use:

```
$item_sum = array_sum( array_map( 'reset', $array));
```

You can see that [this outputs](http://viper-7.com/ezmnjB), based on your input:

```
float(14)
```

Comment: The loop is more obvious about what it's doing. This is clever but arcane.

Comment: OP was trying `array_sum($itemarray[$x][0]);`, this is an example of how to use `array_sum()` like the OP was attempting to accomplish the task.